# Photoshop CC - crop canvas to fit the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was sent an image (.psd) that has transparent background. When I export it the resulting .png preserves the transparent background so the image actually takes more space on a website than necessary. It's a logo image.

I'm trying to adjust the transparent canvas site to only take the space by the image itself.

Alternatively, how do I export it so that the resulting .png is only the size of actual logo (rectangle) not including the transparent space (bigger rectangle).

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To trim off the transparent areas simply use `Image/Trim...` and then select `Transparent Pixels`.

Answer (score 1):

When snap is turned on and you are cropping the image with crop tool it snaps to the pixels of the image. (to keep it in some proportion, you can set aspect ratio for the crop).