# how can I mass edit photos?

Tags: photo-editing, automation

I need to edit a lot of images by removing the background turn it to a PNG and cut it to size, is there a way to automate any part of this all the images are different shapes, the photos have a white background my budget is close to zero and the images are all fairly simple shapes.

Comment: You could automate the first part by uploading them in bulk to an online background removal service… but you didn't mention budget.

Comment: Please have a look at all the questions we already have about [background removal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+removal). The method differs depending on how your images look. To automate it has to be possible to remove background from all images using the same method which shouldn't involve manual steps. If background is completely removed use [this method](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/96144/84899) to trim the image in Photoshop. You don't mention which software you use.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What kind of images?  Background removal can be simple, or complex, and it depends on the images. For example what kind of background do the images have, are they simple or complex, or what are the subject and how complex/simple are they? It may/may not be possible to fully automate it, but there are too many unknowns here. Also what software do you have access to? Please edit your question and provide more information. Thanks